# Internet explorer does not support HTML5 video with height greater than 1088px

Tags: internet-explorer, ffmpeg, html5-video, video-encoding

The company I'm working at writing a web app which allows users to work with media files uploaded from mobile devices.

To unify HTML5 video sources I decided to convert all the videos using H.264 codec in mp4 container and setting width to 1280px.

During the fixing one of the issues with an app I decided to use 4:3 video file with 256x240px resolution. Since I convert all the files to HD resulting file became 1280x1200px and for some reason it isn't playable in IE10 and IE11 (in other browsers going well).

So I spend a lot of time trying to figure out the reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first I decided the reason is in source file and/or output codecs. But experimentally I figured out that it's not. Moreover if I try to use smaller resolutions (like 640x600 or even something weird ones like 1200x1000) it works flawlessly.

Then I tried 1200x1100 and I've got the same issue I had initially. So I started to google on "max video resolution for ie" and found [this blog post](https://lars.st0ne.at/blog/html5+video+in+IE11+-+size+does+matter). Author went further and also experimentally came to the truth that **freaking Internet Explorer does not support videos with a height greater than 1080px!!!** That's really frustrating. Another *pleasant* surprise from MS.

So I hoping this will save someone a few hours of his life and a few hundred of brain cells.